# How to search in prometheus applying binary operator on labels?

Tags: prometheus

Consider that I have metrics of format:- `prometheus_test{Name:"abc", Number:"1",......}`
`prometheus_test{Name:"bcd", Number:"2",......}`
I would like to get metrics with Number>1.
query:- `prometheus_test{Number="1"} will retrieve prometheus_test{Name:"abc", Number:"1",......}`.

What I would like to know is whether there exist a way like `prometheus_test{Number>"1"} to retrieve prometheus_test{Name:"bcd", Number:"2",......}`

I have tried many methods like prometheus_test{Number>"1"} but it shows query error

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus labels are strings and you can't do any processing on them apart from exact or regex matching. You could match everything but 1 using something like `prometheus_test{Number!="1"}`, but that's as much as you'll get out of Prometheus.